# jQuery checkbox work as radio button but reverse back like checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created input-type checkbox fields like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />
```

Now i want checkbox work as radio button like single select. so using jquery is working fine:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).prop("name")+"']";
    $(group).prop("checked",false);
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
});
```

But now if i want to reverse that checkbox work as checkbox using jquery then not working.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use radio buttons?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, because if I will use the radio button and checkbox then two times HTML fields need to add.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya what do you mean? Why would you need to add anything twice? If you want radio button behaviour, use radio buttons. That's why they exist. It's very unclear what the problem is, and your comment doesn't clarify it. Please try to give us a better understanding of your difficulty. P.S. This has nothing to do with PHP, I re-tagged it for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Let's assume i will add exam question right. I need to add question option with answer checkbox. if question type is single choice then only one answer need to select. or if type if multi choice then more then one able to select.

Comment: try to use `value` prop, when you are trying check that particular checkbox

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's why i have used checkbox fields as answers. now I need to checkbox work as a radio button when single choice. it works fine using above jquery logic. But if I select multi-choice then checkbox again work as checkbox

Comment: In that case your server-side code should decide, when rendering the question, whether to render checkboxes or radio buttons, based on the question type. It shouldn't be jQuery's problem. Your proposed solution of messing about with checkboxes is a bodge job. Also, it'll be confusing for the user, because everyone's expectation of checkboxes is that you can select multiple items with them. That's how they're intended. So if you change it so they can only select one, they might think something is wrong with your site. It's far better to give people a standard user experience.

Comment: Completely agree with @ADyson. Your proposed solution is not a secure or robust way to solve the issue you have. The determination of how to render the question, and what controls should be used for selecting the answer(s) needs to be done server side.

Comment: @ADyson No. I think you have not understood my problem. When question insert from admin side then I want to this logic.

Comment: How is the question "inserted from admin side" then exactly? The admin must specify the question type, and/or the number of answers required, I assume? Then I would think the info is saved in a database, ready for using when the user takes the quiz? That means that when your code is deciding how to show the question on the screen for the person taking the quiz, it can look at that information about the number of answers required, and decide whether to make some checkboxes or some radio buttons. I think I've understood quite well, thankyou.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya
There should be some variable which can decide, if current question is multi-choice or single choice and add that logic in code.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I know that it is not good for the user experience.  I just want to know that can I disable and enable the checkbox fields with single and multiple choice

Comment: So you know it's not good, but you want to do it anyway? That makes no sense. Why not just do it properly?? It should be a) simpler, and b) better. There's nothing to lose. This question is a classic [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @ADyson I want to just know can I do that with jquery or not? It's about JQuery.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Make your code (either client-side or server-side) generate _either_ checkboxes or radio buttons, as appropriate. The answers below already demonstrate some solutions with just checkboxes, but I wouldn't use them personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but but you really shouldn't do it. It will lead to a poor user experience, because a user will generally assume that a set of checkboxes means they can select more than one if they wish to. If they see radio buttons, they know they have to make a single choice. If they find a checkbox set where they can't select more than one, it might be frustrating and they may even think there is a bug in your application.

Also, why would you need to "re-enable" anything? Once the question is answered, you would render a new question instead. You wouldn't re-use the same markup for a new question...that doesn't make any sense.

Instead, when rendering each question, make your code (either client-side or server-side, as per your rendering architecture) generate *either* checkboxes or radio buttons, as appropriate, depending on whether your database indicates that the question requires multiple or single answers. This should be both simpler than solutions which manipulate the checkbox behaviour, and will lead to a better UI.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation buddy. i just want to know that how can this possible with jquery manipulation

Comment: Look at the other answers, then. But I cannot understand why you want to continue spending time and energy on a solution you know is not the best, when the better solution would likely be simpler.

Comment: You are right. Just want to know that can I enable multi-select after disable.

Comment: You don't need to, because you should just make a radio button instead. Why would you need to "re-enable" anything? Once the question is answered, you would render a new question instead. You wouldn't re-use the same markup for a new question...that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use radio buttons, but if you must use checkbox:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
  $("input:checkbox").not(this).prop("checked",false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the click handler

```js
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).prop("name")+"']";
        $(group).prop("checked",false);
        $(this).prop("checked",true);
    });
    function disableRadio ( ) {
        $("input:checkbox").unbind();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />   
    <button type="button" onclick="disableRadio()">Disable Radio</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Add Class `multipal`

```
<input type="checkbox" class="multipal" value="1" name="foo" />

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).prop("name")+"']";
    if($(this).hasClass('multipal')){
      $(this).prop("checked",true);  
    }
    else{
      $(group).prop("checked",false);
      $(this).prop("checked",true);
    }
});
```

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).prop("name")+"']";
    if($(this).hasClass('multipal')){
      $(this).prop("checked");  
    }
    else{
      $(group).prop("checked",false);
      $(this).prop("checked",true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="" value="1" name="foo" />

<h2>Multipal<h2>
<input type="checkbox" class="multipal" value="1" name="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="multipal" value="1" name="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="multipal" value="1" name="foo" />
```

Comment: using the simple `.not()` jQuery function is way simpler, see my answer

Comment: Let's assume only above three checkbox exist now I want that it work like radio button and also reverse back as checkbox on some condition

Comment: @VaibhavGarg I mean that how can I enable multi-select again?